# Using Visual Studio 2013 for ASP.NET web site project

Tags: web, visual-studio-2013

I am new to the Visual Studio 2013 IDE / Environment...

I have inherited an older (ASP.NET) web site that is currently being maintained using Microsoft Expression Web 4 (which is no longer supported by Microsoft).  The test and production web sites are hosted remotely using IIS 7.5

I have two questions with regard to migrating from Expression Web 4 to Visual Studio 2013:

1. Is there any way to simply copy (FTP/download) the web site from the production server into Visual Studio 2013?  i.e.: create a new empty web site in VS 2013 and then copy everything from the production web site.    Will this retain “sub-web” folders, etc.?  (I doubt it).
2. When using Expression Web 4 to publish pages to IIS – some of the files in Expression Web are marked as “Exclude from Publishing” (because some files like web.config differ depending if publishing to the test or production server).  I have not found anything in VS 2013 for an ASP.NET web site project that allows me to set individual files so they are excluded from being copied to a remote web site.   Does such functionality even exist?
   Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For #1 Probably not, the production site will not have any source files, just compiled binaries and aspx/css/script files.
For #2 you want to use config transformations, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No the production site does have "source" files in the way of .aspx pages and a single /bin folder for binaries -- this is a web site project not a web application project so I don't think the link applies in this case, but thanks!

Comment: @user1377587 web.config transforms are now supported for both website and web application. :)

Answer (score 0):

For #1 if you have Web Site project open in VS (not to be confused with Web Application project), you can right-click on it and choose Copy Web Site.  This will bring up an window where you can connect to a remote site (e.g. with FTP) and sync files back and forth.

(Note: this feature is ancient and nobody knows about it anymore)

For #2, it depends.  In the case of web.config, you can create a publish profile (right-click the project and choose Publish) that will let you use [web.config transforms](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) to modify the web.config file for each publish destination.  Once your publish profile exists, you can right-click on it in Solution Explorer and choose Add Config Transform, which will only apply when you publish to that destination.

For other files you wish to exclude, you can modify the .pubxml file for your publish profile as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-application-s-project-file.aspx) using `<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>` and `<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>`.  (The blog post talks of editing the project file, but that's no longer necessary since VS2012; use the .pubxml files instead.)

Comment: Jimmy -- I set-up a test WEB SITE project in VS 2013 -- Then tried editing the .pubxml file to include the <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>, but the node is NOT recognized in the editor (via intellisense) -- is this documented anywhere for WEB SITES? -- It is for WEB APPLICATIONS (as per your link), but I do not think it applies to web site projects?

Comment: @user1377587 The files are validated against the MSBuild schema, unfortunately, so any of the web publishing related properties will not show up in intellisense, or will be squiggled in the editor.  It should work if you try publishing though (maybe to a test directory first).

Comment: Jimmy - Thanks again - appears to work when I tried a few tests (but I cannot find any formal documentation from MS).  However, I think I will just build a Powershell script to FTP only those files that have changed.  This will give me the flexibility to be able to exclude specific files AND folders (which can't be done with .pubxml) with ease.